# Do I need to release an MKMapItem or placemark objects?

Tags: iphone, ios6

Of the tutorials I've found online (e.g. http://bit.ly/SIXlI5) and the Apple documentation, none make mention of releasing MKMapItem or the placemarks. Do they need to be released, and if not, why not? Does the Maps app take care of all that?

```
NSDictionary *address = @{
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey: _address.text,
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey: _city.text,
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey: _state.text,
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey: _zip.text
};

MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] 
       initWithCoordinate:_coords 
       addressDictionary:address];

MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];

NSDictionary *options = @{
    MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
};

[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
```

Comment: hi do you have sample of this project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using ARC, and you alloc an object, you are responsible for releasing it. That's all there is to it.

In this case, when you call openInMaps..., the map item info is encoded in a URL that's sent to the Maps app. But you dont need to worry about that.

You can expect that unless it's called out in headers or documentation, an instance method will do its work synchronously and not release the receiver.